# Perl script prompts for password but does not accept input from ksh

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a ksh wrapper script that retrieves a password then calls a perl script, but the perl script thinks that only enter was pressed so keeps prompting.

I cannot change the perl script.

I created a stub Perl script that prompts for input and it accepts that from the wrapper. I have tried `$var | Perl perlscript.pl` and `value | Perl perlscript.pl`. Also tried `perl perlscript.pl << ANSWERS $var ANSWERS` and `echo $var | perl perlscript.pl` and `echo $(derive password) | perl perlscript.pl`.

Comment: How does the Perl script read the password?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Perl script is vendor supplied and I cannot determine how it reads the password

Comment: I have tried $var | Perl perlscript.pl and value | Perl perlscript.pl

Comment: Also tried perl perlscript.pl << ANSWERS $var ANSWERS and echo $var | perl perlscript.pl and echo $(derive password) | perl perlscript.pl

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @spudnik267: As you can see, putting code in comments isn't very helpful. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58113141/edit) to add your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried `$var | Perl perlscript.pl` and `value | Perl perlscript.pl` – spudnik267 Sep 26 at 9:09
>
> Also tried `perl perlscript.pl << ANSWERS $var ANSWERS` and `echo $var | perl perlscript.pl` and `echo $(derive password) | perl perlscript.pl` – spudnik267 Sep 26 at 10:10

Passwords are often not read from STDIN. Instead, they are read directly from the [psuedoterminal or PTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal). This means it's reading from the controlling terminal program, not from STDIN. This is an obsolete security measure meant to make automating filling in passwords harder. To a cracker it's a speed bump, but it's very inconvenient to everyone else.

Here's a simple program echoing input from the PTY.

```
open my $fh, "/dev/tty" or die $!;
print while <$fh>;
```

This program will not see input piped to STDIN. It will only see what you type on the terminal.

There are various ways to talk to a program's PTY. One of the most powerful is to use [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
  
use Expect;

my $exp = Expect->spawn("perl tty.pl") or die $!;
$exp->send("test\n");
$exp->soft_close();
```